# php form submission only once per session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, session

I am looking to enable only one submission of form per session. I have tried to disable submit button but this on click function is nothing for bots so extra layer of single submission per session is what i think can save somewhat from bots

OR

Create token for each submission to make submission more secure and unique

Which one is better and how to implement so any user (bots) can not submit same form twice

Code I have is

```
 <form role="form" method='post' action='index.php' id='cme'>
    <input type="hidden" name="val" value="<?php echo $val ?>" />
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
       <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></di</center>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <center>
            <input type="submit" name="claim" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Claim Now" id="claim" onclick="setTimeout(disableFunction, 1);">
         </center>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Submit section

```
 if(isset($_POST['claim'])) {
$recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!empty($recaptcha)) {
    # Use the recaptcha function here
    $resp   =   getGoogleRecaptcha();
    if($resp['success']) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        # Capture value from the form submit
        $bonval =   $_POST['bonval'];
        # Insert normally
        $db->fetchVal("insert into log (`user_id`,`amount`) values (?,?)", array($id, $bonval));

    } 
}
 else { ?>
<div class="overlay"><div class="popup" style="background:red;">
    <h2>Opps</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a><br/>
    <div><center><span class="blink_me">You missed it</span></center></div>
</div></div>
   <?php  }
 }
```

Now issue is form opens on popup and user keeps clicking and score keeps adding as with each click session view is +1

Can you please guide me about this issue solving so one click and only one submission

I think it can be better to do form submission through javascript so on submit function can be controlled more wisely to kill popup on more than one submit click....am i right, if yes plz guide this way

Comment: You can use of session or cookie..

Comment: Do you want security against bots or do you want that a user can only use the form once per session? Those are different things.

Comment: At present I only want is user restriction to one form submission per session, even if he keep clicking

Comment: You use the word SESSION in your question! That would seem like a possible solution. Keep a var in the session saying `I already submitted`

Comment: anyone with better solution

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of doing this using sessions.
Basically I am generating a token and storing it in session if its not already in session. I am also including the same in the form, which can be cross checked (in `index.php`) to see if it matches with the session variable or not.

```
<?php 
if(! isset($_SESSION['cme-token']) ){
  $cme_token = rand(11111, 99999);
  $_SESSION['cme-token'] = $cme_token;
} ?>

<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['cme'])){ ?>
 <form role="form" method='post' action='index.php' id='cme'>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $cme_token ?>" />
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
       <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></di</center>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <center>
            <input type="submit" name="claim" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Claim Now" id="claim">
         </center>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
<? } else {
  <div>ALREADY CLAIMED!</div>
}?>
```

In index.php you can do additional check just to be sure that the token was not modified in between by user like below.

```
// INDEX.PHP
<?php
  if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['cme-token']) {
    //PROCESS THE FORM
  } else {
    // IGNORE THE FORM SUBMIT AS IT DOESN'T CARRY PROPER TOKEN
  }
?>
```

Comment: and can we do it token way? By making a unique token hidden value in form and then check if token submit is same as session token?

Comment: @john Checkout the answer now.

Comment: @Rao  I have added the submission part of form can you plz look the issue so I can properly stop more than one submission as you can see I have onclick function but users somehow bypass or disable javascript part and keep clicking .... Thnx for kind reply

Comment: HOW to unset or reset token value after successful form submission?